# Read a json file using python

Tags: python, json, file, jupyter-notebook

```
with open('file.json', "r") as input_file:    
    data = json.load(input_file)
print(data)
```

This is my piece of code of reading a json file. It works fine with I run it in a .py, but it gave me error when i put it on Jupyter Notebook as follows:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

The json file looks like this:
[image]
Can anyone help me with it. Thanks

Comment: can you post some part of the json file?

Comment: Try opening with `open('file.json', "r", encoding="utf-8-sig")`. This is just a guess that there might be a BOM character at the beginning.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need read() to import the json into your file according to this:

```
with open('sample_tweets.json', "r") as input_file:    
    data = json.load(input_file.read())
```

I could not verify it with your json file, but that is the way it works for me.

Comment: yeah the strangest thing is that it worked for me if I put code in .py but failed when i run it on Jupyter Notebook

Comment: According to the documentation for `json.load`, the first argument, `fp`, is described thus: **Deserialize `fp` (a .read()-supporting text file or binary file containing a JSON document) to a Python object using this conversion table.** `input_file.read()` returns a string and since `json.load` expects an object that has a `read` method, which a string does *not* have, this could not have worked for you. You must have used method `loads` but that would be no real difference than the OP's answer.